# Is there a performance penalty for a unique constraint on GUID field

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a unique constraint on a GUID field. Is there a performance penalty for doing this? I have read online that putting an index on a GUID field can cause fragmentation. Will unique constraints suffer from fragmentation?

Comment: Perhaps you should look up what the letters g u i d actually stand for.

Comment: @DanBracuk Yes, I am calculating a MD5 hash on a large piece of text and ensuring the text is unique. This is the reason there is a unique index on the field.

Comment: @Luke101 it depends what is your requirement . ie. Looking for read or write ... fragmentation will decrease insert performance down.

Comment: @sandeeprawat I need the unique index for write. I will not be reading from the table it will only be writing.

Comment: in that case y you need to create index .. create index with fill factor 50...

Comment: Performance penalty is relative term index on int will crate  smaller b+ as it is only 8bit but in case of guid it is  more than 32 bit

Comment: MD5 hash != GUID.

Answer (score 2):

if you are using index  and not using a good index key,you will have to pay cost of fragmentation.Though,how it affects you,[depends on the way you query](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2014/11/index-fragmentation-matter/)

Unique constraint ,will be enforced as unique non clustered index under the covers..below is a small example of fragmentation for unique constraint

**Demo:**

```
create table dbo.temp
(
id int identity ,
guidd  uniqueidentifier unique  default newid()
)



insert into dbo.temp
(guidd)
select NEWID()
go 1000

select object_name(object_id) as name,index_id,index_type_desc,avg_fragmentation_in_percent
 from sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats(0,0,null,null,null)
 where object_id=object_id('temp')

name    index_id    index_type_desc   avg_fragmentation_in_percent
temp    0             HEAP                0
temp    2            NONCLUSTERED INDEX   75
```

You have to pay the penalty for maintaining the non clustered index irrespective of whether the table is heap or clustered(leaving aside storage considerations). Since  every insert/delete/update operation on clustered index/heap  will require two operations.one to modify clustered index or heap,one to modify non clustered index